Error 503 - ORA-28000: The account is locked - Oracle APEX
These days when I tried to sign in to oracle APEX , I faced

Error 503 - ORDS was unable to make a connection to the database. ORDS
is not able to proxy to the target user because that user is locked.
The connection pool named: |default|lo| had the following error(s):
ORA-28000: The account is locked.

when I run this query :
select * from dba_users
where USERNAME like '%APEX%'

I see that the APEX_XXXXXX user is open but the APEX_LISTENER is locked !
Even I check the DEFAULT profile's PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME is set to UNLIMITED .
I unlocke the APEX_LISTENER user then I can sign up in APEX but the next day , again I see APEX_LISTENER is locked
The ORDS version is : 23.2.1.r2001208
please help me through this error.

If the APEX_PUBLIC_USER account is locked, unlock it. Also, what version of ORDS?

the question is updated . I unlock the APEX_LISTENER user but the next day , it becomes locked

Audit login attempts so that you can determine who or what is locking out the account. Has the password recently been changed? Is there a service that wasn't updated that might still be using the old password?

sounds like you hav a connection pool configured with a bad password, so it keeps getting locked
